# Using ConstraintLayout in CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to use ConstraintLayout inside CardView for so that I can inflate it for a RecyclerView?

Current layout is like this but I want to display it inside a CardView.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeArp.png

Reference XML code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/touch_selector"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_padding_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_item_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_item_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_padding_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:src="@drawable/art_clouds"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_date_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/list_item_date_start_margin"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/weather_icon"
        tools:text="Today, April 03"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="Rainy"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/high_temperature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/forecast_temperature_space"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/forecast_temperature_space"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/forecast_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/low_temperature"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="19\u00b0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/low_temperature"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/forecast_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="10\u00b0"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put this ConstraintLayout inside the CardView?

Answer (score 9):

Yep, it's possible! Put your `ConstraintLayout` xml code inside `CardView`. You can also check out various [card view implementations](http://eugenebrusov.com/cardview-with-constraintlayout/) done in compliance with [Material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks).

Comment: The site linked here is nice

Answer (score 2):

You have `ConstraintLayout` in the parent. Use it inside `CardView` for having `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/animals" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalJokes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Androidx use it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
android:clickable="true"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_radius">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/firsthline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/firstvline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/secondvline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/text_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/text_padding"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/cuvantprincipal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/text_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/text_padding"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/cuvantsecundar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playbutton"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```